# Good UCI to WinBoard adapter

Tags: engines, software, uci, winboard

I found one before on the internet but it keeps the CPU at 100%, hangs a lot, and doesn't exit when the program (ChessMaster in this case) closes.

Answer (score 2):

UCI2WB which you can find it in [Winboard](http://hgm.nubati.net/) packages.

[PolyGlot](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/details1/PolyGlot.html) is another option.

Many modern chess GUIs doesn't need external converter such as ChessX, Fritz, ...